# Why axios in not fetching response in case of error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am trying to implement a signup demo. Backend has been written in node.js and frontend in react.

Here is my error handling middleware(in index.js):

```
app.use((error,req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(error);
    const status= error.statusCode || 500;
    const message= error.message;
    res.status(status).json({message: message});
})
```

Whenever my `password` and `confirm password` do not match I get the following message in the console:

```
Error: Passwords do not match
    at exports.postSignup (D:\program\auth-bh-demo\server\Controllers\login.js:43:22)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\program\auth-bh-demo\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\program\auth-bh-demo\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\program\auth-bh-demo\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\program\auth-bh-demo\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\program\auth-bh-demo\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (D:\program\auth-bh-demo\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:341:12) 
    at next (D:\program\auth-bh-demo\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (D:\program\auth-bh-demo\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (D:\program\auth-bh-demo\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12) {
  statusCode: 422
```

Here is my frontend code to receive errors:

```
const onSubmitHandler=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/signup',{name,emailId,password,confirmPassword})
            .then(response=>{
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                console.log(err.message);
                setError(err.message);
            })
    }
```

In case of success I get a response with all details of the newly created user but in case of an unsuccessful post request, I get no response.
In the console I see:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 422
    at createError (createError.js:16:1)
    at settle (settle.js:17:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66:1)
```

This error has the same status as passed by me in the backend, but with no message.

I am sure that my backend is sending the error message but unable to understand why Axios is not fetching the response in case of an unsuccessful post request.

Please help me with this also let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll want to use `err.response.data`, though keep in mind that the response property can be `undefined` if you don't actually receive a response.

**EDIT**

I've never used Express, but I don't believe your error middleware is ever used. The `.catch` of the axios call catches the error before your middleware can process it. If you were to throw the error at the end of the axios call, it'd get caught by your middleware. You can either remove the axios `.catch` clause and move your `setError` logic into your middleware or you could go with my first recommendation to get the error message correctly.

**EDIT 2**

If the `.catch` is appended to the `.then` like above, it can end up catching exceptions that occur in the `.then`. You can get around that by implementing something like below.

```
let request = axios.post('http://localhost:8080/signup',{name,emailId,password,confirmPassword});
request.then(response=>{
   console.log(response);
});
request.catch(err=>{
   console.log(err.message);
   setError(err.message);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help by using ``err.response.data`` I was able to receive the message sent by the backend but not the status code.  I have a doubt, isn't ``.catch`` is responsible to catch errors when we try to ``get or post`` data from the wrong ``URL``, but since in my case I was passing the right ``URL`` I think my error must have come in response of ``.then()``. please correct me if I am wrong as I am just learning node and react.

Comment: I double-checked whether my error middleware was reached or not. I am totally convinced that it is being reached.

Comment: @Pawan I guess I was wrong about the middleware, like I said, not too familiar with Express. The axios `.catch` will catch any response from the server that doesn't have a 2xx status code.

Comment: @Pawan A pitfall that I ran into before is that if you append the `.then` and `catch` like that any exception occured in the `.then` will be caught in the `.catch`. It can cause issues if you're expecting that error object to be of a certain form. You can get around that by doing something like the my most recent edit above.

Comment: @Pawan Since all you're doing is logging the response, an exception wouldn't be thrown from there. But figured it be good to know for future reference in how promises work.